# Set custom class object's value with '=' operator in Java

Tags: java, custom-object

I have a custom object that has a single value of type int that I wanting to do processing on to keep this value in a set range. My question is this: Given the following class, can I set it's value with myObject = 0;

```
public class foo{
    private int bar;
    public foo(){
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a method public void setBar()

Answer (score 5):

If you mean:

```
foo x = new foo();
x = 10; // This is meant to set x.bar
```

then no, you can't do that in Java. Good thing too, if you ask me... it would be horrible in terms of readability.

You *also* can't change it to allow:

```
foo x = 10;
```

as equivalent to:

```
foo x = new foo();
x.bar = 10; // Or x.setBar(10);
```

Comment: I think it would be nice for working with matrices... but obviously not for this example.

Comment: Access modifier of bar isn't public, so that has to be changed too if you want to set x.bar

Comment: @ShivaKumar: I was assuming that would be the case. Although the code could be called from the same class, of course :)

Comment: Can't agree more.  In my opinion the readability weighs more than that it is not possible to overload operators in Java.  I wouldn't recommend doing it if it were possible.

Comment: As far as the readability, I am essentially trying to create a custom data type that works like an int with a range constraint. In-use it will read much nicer that get/set methods(my whole reasoning in wanting this). I need to run some code when the value is set to make sure it is in range, otherwise throw an exception(this coding I have already done). So yes, it must be private unless (as asked below in a different comment) I am able to listen for a public value to be changed so a private method may be automatically called to process.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do that. Java does not support operator overloading. Although `+` operator is overloaded for performing String concatenation, but that's the only exception. Another example that uses the `=` operator the way you would want is in case of wrapper classes, where you can directly assign a primitive type values to it's corresponding wrapper type, which causes the primitive value to be auto-boxed to wrapper type.

```
Integer val = 10;  // 10 is auto-boxed to Integer reference
```

But it's only limited for that purpose. You can't do that for your own user-defined type.

Creating a method is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo myObject = new Foo();`

Here, `myObject` holds the reference. You can't assign primitive value such as 0 to object references.

Instead, you should do `myObject.setBar(10);`

Answer (score 0):

No, it goes against encapsulation logic, and Java Itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the convention is to provide setters and getters to change an object's inner attributes. For your case:

```
foo instance = new foo();
instance.setBar(10); //Sets bar to 10
instance.getBar(); //returns bar's current value (right now 10)
```

The setter receives the new value and sets it:

```
public void setBar(int newBar) {
    bar = newBar;
}
```

And the getter gives access to the field's current value:

```
public int getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

You cannot, however, overload the `=` operator to do as `setBar` does, at least in Java. If you're thinking about, for example the `Integer` or `Float` wrapper classes, there's another force at work there, related to Java's implementation itself and that later derives in the concepts of *boxing* and *unboxing*.

Comment: You mean to say `foo.setBar(10)` or `instance.setBar(10)`?

Comment: As a side note: Please follow Java's naming convention. Classes should start with an Uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Abother possibility, you could make this field public. It would just need to do the validations you need in the business method (no during the set).

Comment: This is something I had considered, but then my question is, inside the constructor can I put some sort of listener on the then public field so that I may do some processing as soon as its changed without having to manually call some sort of .process() method?