# How to set an object equal to a literal?

Tags: java, literals

I am wanting to create an object that can store an integer value and call various methods on it. The code is like this

```
public class IntegerUtil{
private int value;

public IntegerUtil(int a){
this.value = a;
}

//insert methods here

}
```

When I instantiate an IntegerUtil object, I do something like

```
IntegerUtil iu = new IntegerUtil(5); //this does compile
```

I would prefer to do this instead of typing out the entire constructor.

```
IntegerUtil iu = 5; //this does not compile
```

The compiler doesn't accept this as valid syntax because I am setting a non primitive data type equal to a literal. But it is possible to do this. I noticed that the java.lang.Integer class can be set equal to a literal.

```
int integer = 5; //primitive data type set equal to literal
Integer integer = 5; //object set equal to literal - how to do this?
Integer integer = new Integer(5); //object being instantiated with constructor
//all three of these compile with no problem
```

Is there a way I can make my IntegerUtil object behave like the java.lang.Integer class in that it can be initialized as a literal?

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is a special compiler feature for specific primitive wrappers. You can't apply it on your own.

Comment: If you want a slightly shorter syntax, you can create a static factory method and use a static import to do `IntegerUtil iu = wrap(5);`.

Comment: You'd need something like Swift's `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, but there is no such thing in Java. You'll have to live with calling a constructor or factory method.

Comment: @thilo What was the problem with the duplicate?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It talks more about how to make Map literals, not how to do something like `MyObject x = 123`. So I think this one deserves a fresh answer (or another duplicate).

Comment: @Thilo I think it's pretty clear that it means _any literal syntax_ is disallowed for custom types and even lists all the solutions proposed here in the comments.

Comment: @Thilo [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386773/set-custom-class-objects-value-with-operator-in-java).

Comment: Related: [initialize object directly in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005584/initialize-object-directly-in-java)